# Ruby on Rails 6+ jquery did not work in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Chrome:

```
VM17:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.js:283)
    at rails-ujs.js:196
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.js:264)
```

view x.js.erb

```
$(#new).hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the argument passed to jQuery to make it a string:

```
$('#new').hide();
```

Comment: I'm blind. Thanks!